# prime zeta function when $0<s<1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, zeta-functions

I will not be surprised if this question seems trivial in MO but I asked it first in MathSE and I did not get an answer.  Here is the question:
I would like  to know if there is a good estimate for the sum which concerns all primes not exceeding $x$:
 $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^s}$$
with $0 < s < 1$. I have trouble bounding the sum from above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is not reserch level question. But you can find nice bounds for prime zeta function in this doctoral thesishttp://www.math.sjsu.edu/~goldston/tsang1.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany I know it is not.As I mention above i hoped that someone here might have the kind intention to help me and answer my question.Thank you for the responce!

Comment: "I will not be surprised if this question seems trivial in MO but i asked it first in MathSE and i did not get an answer." 
In fact, it has already been asked and answered several times on math.stackexchange. [See here for a comprehensive answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434) which shows that for $k>-1$, $$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{k}=\text{li}\left(x^{k+1}\right)+O\left(x^{k+1}e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right).$$

For this reason I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give the following 
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^s} \approx \frac{1}{1-s}\frac{x^{1-s}}{\log x}$$
for $0\leq s < 1$ and 
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p} \approx \log \log x$$
for $s = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responce!What methods did you use?Is it possible to arrive at this estimate without the prime number theorem?Using Chebyshev estimates for example

Answer (score 0):

This estimate is probably very crude, but here we have that $\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p^s} \leq \pi(x)\frac{1}{2^s}$.

Comment: For such a crude estimate it is not that bad,but it is really far from truth.